# How to pass a setter method to the argument to a method in Java?

Tags: java

Quick question about refactoring a method, and how to pass a setter method as a method in Java.

I used to have a legacy method that is getting bigger and bigger, The legacy method really just update for a customer ID, by what means (email, telephone, fax, twitter, etc...) we contacted the customer, such as:

```
 final Map<Integer, Customer> customerID_and_customer_Map = getCustomerIDandCustomerContactedByXXXMap();

        for (final Integer customerId : getListOfCustomersContactedByTelephone()) {
            if (customerID_and_customer_Map.containsKey(customerId)) {
                final Customer customer = customerID_and_customer_Map.get(customerId);
                customer.setCustomerContactedByTelephone(true);
                customer.setCustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce(true);
                customerID_and_customer_Map.put(customerId, customer);
            }
        }
        for (final Integer customerId : getListOfCustomersContactedByTwitter()) {
            if (customerID_and_customer_Map.containsKey(customerId)) {
                final Customer customer = customerID_and_customer_Map.get(customerId);
                customer.setPartnerContactedByTwitter(true);
                customer.setCustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce(true);
                customerID_and_customer_Map.put(customerId, customer);
            }
        }
```

With time, we are just adding for loop for each new way of contact to partner. And this method who started with two for loops, now have some 50ish.

```
final Map<Integer, Customer> customerID_and_customer_Map = getCustomerIDandCustomerContactedByXXXMap();
        for (final Integer customerId : getListOfCustomersContactedByTelephone()) {
            if (customerID_and_customer_Map.containsKey(customerId)) {
                final Customer customer = customerID_and_customer_Map.get(customerId);
                customer.setCustomerContactedByTelephone(true);
                customer.setCustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce(true);
                customerID_and_customer_Map.put(customerId, customer);
            }
        }
        for (final Integer customerId : getListOfCustomersContactedByTwitter()) {
            if (customerID_and_customer_Map.containsKey(customerId)) {
                final Customer customer = customerID_and_customer_Map.get(customerId);
                customer.setPartnerContactedByTwitter(true);
                customer.setCustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce(true);
                customerID_and_customer_Map.put(customerId, customer);
            }
        }
        for (final Integer customerId : getListOfCustomersContactedByEmail()) {
            if (customerID_and_customer_Map.containsKey(customerId)) {
                final Customer customer = customerID_and_customer_Map.get(customerId);
                customer.setPartnerContactedByEmail(true);
                customer.setCustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce(true);
                customerID_and_customer_Map.put(customerId, customer);
            }
        }
//and lot more for loops for other ways, like fax, LinkedIn, pager, advertisement, etc etc etc
```

As of today, this method is now a page long!

I would like to refactor this block, to make the code cleaner, and came up with this.

```
    private static void magicMethod(Map<Integer, Customer> map, List<Integer> customersContactedByXXX) {
        for (final Integer customerId : customersContactedByXXX) {
            if (map.containsKey(customerId)) {
                final Customer customer = map.get(customerId);
//                customer.setPartnerContactedByXXX(true); <---- How to do this part?
                customer.setCustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce(true);
                map.put(customerId, customer);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the setter in the for loop is the problematic part.

How to do this the most efficient way? Or maybe there is a way to pass a setter as argument of a method?

I understand there should be a better way to do the whole thing in the first place. My goal is really to ask how to refactor all those for loops into one single for loop. Not to refactor the whole thing please.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: For those logical values i would use an `enum`, and you could pass the constants, istead of the setters...

Comment: Rather than refactoring the way you suggested, how about declaring an enum such as `ContactMethod` with constants such as `TELEPHONE`, `TWITTER`, `EMAIL` etc? Then you'd have one method called `getListOfCustomersContactedBy` that accepts a `ContactMethod`, and customers will also have one setter that accepts two arguments - a `ContactMethod` and a `boolean`. Then you can just loop through the `values()` of the enum.

Comment: Agree with you Sweeper. However, I would like to resolve this by refactoring in one single for loop first. I am blocked on the setter part. Do not want to do the entire refactoring yet. I understand there are many other ways to do this cleaner. Appriciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java 8, maybe something like this?

```
magicMethod(getCustomerIDandCustomerContactedByXXXMap(),  getListOfCustomersContactedByTwitter(), MyClass::contactedCustomerByTwitter);

private static void magicMethod(Map<Integer, Customer> map, List<Integer> customersContactedByXXX, Consumer<Customer> contactedConsumer) {
    for (final Integer customerId : customersContactedByXXX) {
        if (map.containsKey(customerId)) {
            final Customer customer = map.get(customerId);
            contactedConsumer.accept(customer);
            customer.setCustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce(true);
            map.put(customerId, customer);
        }
    }
}

private static void contactedCustomerByTwitter(Customer customer) {
   customer.setPartnerContactedByTwitter(true);
}
```

Comment: (and it is .accept, not .apply, but I got the idea, and it is working)

Comment: upvoted for fairness, you gave the answer regarding socket server new line not being sent before me.

Answer (score 2):

In each loop, a pair of methods are different:

```
for (final Integer customerId : getListOfCustomersContactedByTelephone()) {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (customerID_and_customer_Map.containsKey(customerId)) {
        final Customer customer = customerID_and_customer_Map.get(customerId);
        customer.setCustomerContactedByTelephone(true);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        customer.setCustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce(true);
        customerID_and_customer_Map.put(customerId, customer);
    }
}
```

So you can put these "pairs" in two lists:

```
List<Supplier<List<Customer>>> customerListSuppliers = List.of(
   YourClass::getListOfCustomersContactedByTwitter,
   YourClass::getListOfCustomersContactedByTelephone,
   YourClass::getListOfCustomersContactedByEmail,
   ...
)

List<BiConsumer<Customer, Boolean>> customerSetters = List.of(
   Customer::setPartnerContactedByTwitter,
   Customer::setPartnerContactedByTelephone,
   Customer::setPartnerContactedByEmail,
   ...
)
```

If you are not using Java 9+, just `add` those method references into two regular `ArrayList`s.

Then, loop through both lists!

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < customerListSuppliers.size() ; i ++) {
    Supplier<List<Customer>> customerListSupplier = customerListSuppliers.get(i);
    BiConsumer<Customer, Boolean> customerSetter = customerSetters.get(i);
    for (final Integer customerId : customerListSupplier.get()) {
        if (customerID_and_customer_Map.containsKey(customerId)) {
            final Customer customer = customerID_and_customer_Map.get(customerId);
            customerSetter.accept(customer, true);
            customer.setCustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce(true);
            customerID_and_customer_Map.put(customerId, customer);
        }
    }
}
```

Some other points:

- I don't think you need to put the customer back into the map.
- Consider setting `CustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce` to true automatically in `setPartnerContactedByXXX`, if the argument is `true`.
- Consider making a `ContactMethod` enum that has all these contact methods. And make the methods accept a `ContactMethod`, rather than having one method for each contact method.

Answer (score 0):

as a first step you could move each for loop to a method, e.g.

```
private updateCustomersContactedByTelephone() {
for (final Integer customerId : getListOfCustomersContactedByTelephone()) {
            if (customerID_and_customer_Map.containsKey(customerId)) {
                final Customer customer = customerID_and_customer_Map.get(customerId);
                customer.setCustomerContactedByTelephone(true);
                customer.setCustomerHasBeenContactedAtLeastBySomethingOnce(true);
                customerID_and_customer_Map.put(customerId, customer);
            }
        }
}
```

and then call the method instead. Then look for "similar" updates and again group them together in a method.

Comment: Agree Marc, thanks. I have extracted all for loops from the "main method". The "main method looks much nicer, only the 50ish lines, which invokes the 50 real for loops from an utility class. However, I would also like to refactor the for loop, but blocked on the setter part